# Passing parameter between two pages without using the url in JSF and session's variable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page object.xhtml which display the list of objects. I want to click on one object and show its details on another page. I don't want to pass parameter via the url or using session's variable.

Comment: What component are you using for displaying the objects, datatable?

Comment: I want to display these objects in a a form and allow the user to edit them

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a  `p:datatable`  you can create a column to redirect to an edit page:

```
                <p:column headerText="Action">
                    <p:commandLink ajax="false" title="Edit" action="target.xhtml"
                        value="Edit">
                        <f:param name="objectId" value="#{object.id}" />                        
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
```

And in your backing bean you can use the parameter like this:

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String objectId = context.getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap().get("objectId");
```